# Berkeley DB fails on iPhone in DbEnv::open(char const*, unsigned int, int)

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, berkeley-db, bitcoin

I'm trying to use Berkeley DB for a Bitcon project.
On simulator the project works perfectly. On the device, it fails in DbEnv::open(char const*, unsigned int, int), with this message:

```
************************
EXCEPTION: 11DbException       
DbEnv::open: Operation not supported on socket       
bitcoin in AppInit()
```

All used paths correspond to sandbox restrictions:

```
Default data directory /private/var/mobile/Applications/CA8DA82B-0540-459F-A634-6BA4A43F9E70/Library/.bitcoin
Loading addresses...
dbenv.open strLogDir=/var/mobile/Applications/CA8DA82B-0540-459F-A634-6BA4A43F9E70/Documents/database strErrorFile=/var/mobile/Applications/CA8DA82B-0540-459F-A634-6BA4A43F9E70/Documents/db.log
```

**UPDATE**: On a jailbroken phone still crashes. It means that the issue is not caused by sandbox.

Has anyone met such problems while using Berkeley DB on iPhone?Does anyone know how to fix this problems?

Comment: instruments is your friend - trace system calls of the process to find the root cause of the exception

Comment: What simulator / real devices are you using?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, iOS7.0 &iOS 6.0 Simulator, iPhone 4s with iOS7 and iPhone4 with iOS6.1